# Algebraically Independence of polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Are the polynomials $(xy+xt+zt)t$, $(x+z)t^2$, $(x+z)(y+t)t$, $(y+t)(xy+xt+zt)$ algebraically independent ? If not what are all the relations between them. I tried to compute the determinant of the Jacobian matrix but the computation looks difficult. Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the polynomials $f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4$ in the order they appear in the question.
Then

$$(*) \quad f_1 f_3 - f_2 f_4 = 0.$$

So all together they are algebraically dependent. 
Pairwise or in groups of three they are algebraically independent.

You can compute this result by grobner base methods. Take the map $\phi$ from ${\mathbb Q}[F_1,\ldots,F_4]$ to ${\mathbb Q}[x,y,z,t]$ that maps $F_i \mapsto f_i$. Then compute the kernel of $\phi$. It gives the relation $(*)$ from above, but none else.
The computation can be easily done with Macaulay 2.